# MSB3030 Could not copy the file "C:\Repository\DESIGN-PATTERNS\DesingPatterns\WorkSingleton\obj\Debug\net7.0\apphost.exe" because it was not found

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am building my project, but happens this error always↓

Any ideia to solved this issue?

I am trying solved this problem in VS

Comment: You do not have permission to write to folder.  From VS go to menu File : Save As and store project in a folder you have permission to write.